# What happens if I execute an SKAction run sequence on a node that is already executing another sequence?

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have an **SKSpriteNode** with an **SKAction** being run on it:

```
theGem!.run(premAction, completion: {theGem!.run(repeatAction)})
```

Can't seem to find out the proper steps to run another action, such as:

```
theGem.run(endsequence, completion: {theGem.removeAllActions(); theGem.run(stopAction)})
```

Should I stop the previous action first?
Is there a way to turn the repeat part off so that the first SKAction ends smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

Typically SKActions are combined when 2 or more are run at once.

To run a sequence of SKActions you would usually use something like this, where `premAction` is run first, followed by `repeatAction`

```
let sequence1 = SKAction.sequence([premAction, repeatAction])
```

To run the sequence use:

```
theGem.run(sequence1)
```

If the plan is to run another SKAction sequence at some point, you can use:

```
theGem.removeAllActions()
theGem.run(sequence2)
```

Alternatively, if you prefer more closely monitored action management, whenever you run an action assign it a key like this:

```
theGem.run(sequence1, withKey "seq1key")
```

Then, when you want to stop that particular action, use:

```
theGem.removeAction(forKey: "seq1key")
```

Comment: So I should remove a running sequence if it's on repeat, "before" running a new one? p.s. Thanks for the key tip.

Comment: If the running sequence is no longer needed then yes, remove it. Running a new SKAction on a sprite will not stop the other actions currently running on it.